# Real-world set theory/combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I have a real-world problem, and, unfortunately, being an engineer, I feel compelled to solve it.

I went to Walmart the other day and attempted to purchase eleven over-the-counter (OTC) health-related products totaling $104.07.

At checkout, $$61.54  of the total was approved for payment by my insurance OTC benefit card, while $42.53 of the total was not approved (which I paid for in cash.)

The receipt does NOT indicate which items were approved and which were not.

The problem I'm trying to solve is: Which items were approved and which were not?

The eleven items and their costs are as follows:

- Gauze pads       2.34
- Alcohol          3.48
- Antibiotic cream 4.12
- Lidocaine cream  4.94
- Bandages         4.97
- Hydrocortisone   7.12
- Peptobismol      8.56
- Toothpaste      10.59
- Melatonin       13.76
- Ibuprofan 19.71
- Loratadine 24.48

In summary:
There are eleven elements in total divided into two sets.

Set "A" contains "n" elements totaling $61.54.

Set "B" contains "11-n" elements totaling $42.53.

What are the "n" elements contained in set "A"?

I don't have a clue as to how to go about solving this.

I do realize, however, that there may be more than one solution to this problem.

Edit: Taxes have been removed from the totals.

Comment: Just to be sure, are the individual prices and the overall total taken before or after tax? If the individual prices are taken before tax and the overall total is taken after tax, that will need to be a consideration

Comment: This seems like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is NP complete. Of course, in this case, you can just try all $2^{10}$ partitions (reduced from $2^{11}$ because you don't care which of the two parts an item ends up in).

Comment: More specifically, the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: @peterwhy: Oops, not just more specifically, more correctly! :-)

Comment: $61.54$ can be achieved one way.  So too can $61.52$ and $61.57$, while $61.51$ can be achieved two ways

Comment: There are $2^{11}=2048$ possible combinations so you can check them all.  I am surprised if Toothpaste is one of the items apparently covered by insurance.  And Ibuprofen (spelling) costs about $\$0.50$ OTC in the UK so $\$19.71$ looks high

Comment: Yes, toothpaste is covered along with many items that actually would surprise you. All of the items in the list should have been covered.

Comment: Um..., I substituted Ibuprofen as the name for a more personal item...

Comment: Henry, would you be so kind as to share your solution?

Comment: Not really - there are people here who dislike such answers.  But I simply tried all $2048$ possibilities

Comment: @JohnE Given the nature of your question, I'm perfectly willing to tell you my answer: it's the gauze, the alcohol, the bandages, the hydrocortisone, the peptobismol, the toothpaste, and the loratadine. My implementation for the solution can be found [here](https://replit.com/@StephenDonovan1/FakeEcstaticApplicationprogram#main.py) if you'd like to take a look, I think it's a bit better than just generating all possible gatherings of elements, but in the grand scheme of things probably not by much

Comment: One way to solve such problems (for small values of $n$) is to formulate the problem as a binary integer programming problem and then find a solution using the Excel Solver.

Comment: @awkward That is an excellent idea. I came across Excel Solver a few years ago when I was working to solve an especially sticky kinematics problem. Last night, going to sleep, I was thinking about trying to solve it as a binary integer programming problem as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set A = 61.54 = [('Gauze pads', 2.34), ('Alcohol', 3.48), ('Bandages', 4.97), ('Hydrocortisone', 7.12), ('Peptobismol', 8.56), ('Toothpaste', 10.59), ('Loratadine', 24.48)]

But I cheated...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

sumA = 61.54
sumB = 42.53

thing = (("Gauze pads", 2.34),
         ("Alcohol", 3.48),
         ("Antibiotic cream", 4.12),
         ("Lidocaine cream", 4.94),
         ("Bandages", 4.97),
         ("Hydrocortisone", 7.12),
         ("Peptobismol", 8.56),
         ("Toothpaste", 10.59),
         ("Melatonin", 13.76),
         ("Ibuprofen", 19.71),
         ("Loratadine", 24.48)
)

def subset (thing, k):
    # Return k-th subset and its complement.
    s0, s1 = [], []
    for t in thing:
        if k % 2 == 0:
            s0.append (t)
        else:
            s1.append (t)
        k //= 2
    return s0, s1

def subsum (s):
    # Sum the costs.
    return sum (e[1] for e in s)

def equals (a, b):
    # Needed due to IEEE-754 floating-point quirks.
    return abs(a - b) < 1e-8

sumAB = subsum (thing)

if not equals (sumAB, sumA + sumB):
    print ("No solution")
else:
    for k in range (2 ** len(thing)):
        s0, _ = subset (thing, k)
        if equals (subsum(s0), sumA):
            print ("Set A = %.2f =" % sumA, s0)
```